# Populate Rails 4 form with JSON object gathered from URL input in form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json

What I am trying to do is fill in a form in Rails 4 with data being received from a JSON object.

```
#_form.html.erb  
<%= simple_form_for(@tournament) do |f| %>
 <%= f.input :url %>
 <%= f.input :name %>
 <%= f.input :location %>
 <%= f.input :start_time, :as => :hidden %>
 <%= f.input :end_time, :as => :hidden %>
 <%= f.input :entrants, :as => :hidden %>
 <%= f.input :t_id, :as => :hidden %>
 <%= f.input :type, :as => :hidden %>
 <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

How do I take the input URL and use the received JSON object to populate the rest of the fields?

Comment: What is question here?

Comment: I reworded it. I want to take a URL input and use the JSON object from the URL to populate the rest of the fields.

Answer (score 2):

If I've well understood you're problem is not in the view but in the controller. Just check how you're building the `@tournament` object.

Normally if something like :

```
@tournament = Tournament.new(params[:tournament])
```

on the JS side you should post parameters in this way :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/tournaments',
    dataType : 'json',
    data: { tournament: {t_id: 1, ...} }
});
```